# MSAL error "parsing_wstrust_response_failed" when trying to use AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth

Tags: azure, adal

I'm attempting to acquire a token from AD or Azure AD but my call to AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth results in this:

*MSAL.Desktop.4.14.0.0.MsalClientException: 
ErrorCode: parsing_wstrust_response_failed
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: An error occurred while sending the request. 
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. 
---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. 
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request. Please try again later*

According to the team that registered my app in Azure I'm a public client and I've got rights to use 'user.read'

Any idea what could be up so that I can communicate something back to our firm's Azure team. It could be my fault, their fault or MS's fault, I'd just like to know who to complain to. Most of the code is generated by the Azure portal, I just changed the call to AcquireTokenInteractive to AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth since my final goal is to silently get the token all the time.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string graphAPIEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";
        string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void CallGraphButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
            var app = App.PublicClientApp;
            ResultText.Text = string.Empty;
            TokenInfoText.Text = string.Empty;

            var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
            var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

            try
            {
                authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

                try
                {
                    authResult = await app.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(scopes)
                        .ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None);
                }
                catch (MsalException msalex)
                {
                    ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
                }
            }


    public partial class App : Application
    {
        static App()
        {
            _clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                .WithAuthority($"{Instance}{Tenant}")
                .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
                .Build();
            TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(_clientApp.UserTokenCache);
        }

        private static string ClientId = "<My Client ID>";
        private static string Tenant = "<Our Tenant ID>";
        private static string Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
        private static IPublicClientApplication _clientApp ;

        public static IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApp { get { return _clientApp; } }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Integrated-Windows-Authentication, there are a number of constraints surrounding the `AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth` method.

If you are testing with your own user account, consent must be granted to the application for your account. Also, 2FA cannot be enabled when using this Auth flow.

For other users, they will need to consent to the application accessing their account details, or the tenant admin must grant consent across the tenant using the `Grant admin consent for Tenant` button in the portal.

This flow only applies to "federated users" (e.g. created in AD rather than AzureAD).

This flow is targeted primarily at desktop applications. It only works with .net desktop, .net core and Windows Universal Apps.

Comment: Still you can handle this exception in your application end in a meaningfull way and show it to the end user or use it for your troubleshooting purpose. Like the following,

try
{
}
catch (MsalClientException ex) when (ex.ErrorCode == "parsing_wstrust_response_failed")
  {
   // In the case of a Federated user (that is owned by a federated IdP, as opposed to a managed user owned in an Azure AD tenant). The security token could not be authenticated or authorized. The user does not exist or has entered the wrong password
  }